# How to completely animate pathLength of svg to 0 in framer-motion?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion, svg-animate

I am trying to animate a svg path to disappear on click. The animation works, but at the end of the animation a dot is left behind.

Here is my code

```js
export default function App() {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => setShowPassword((prev) => !prev)}>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        stroke="#000"
        strokeWidth="1.5"
      >
        <path
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          d="M2.036 12.322a1.012 1.012 0 010-.639C3.423 7.51 7.36 4.5 12 4.5c4.638 0 8.573 3.007 9.963 7.178.07.207.07.431 0 .639C20.577 16.49 16.64 19.5 12 19.5c-4.638 0-8.573-3.007-9.963-7.178z"
        />
        <path
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z"
        />
        <motion.path
          initial={{ pathLength: 1, opacity: 1 }}
          animate={{ pathLength: showPassword ? 0 : 1 }}
          exit={{ pathLength: 1 }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.2, ease: "easeInOut" }}
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          d="M3 3L21 21"
        />
      </svg>
    </button>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-eye-mxkh4p?file=/src/App.js)

I am expecting the animation to completely remove the svg path.

Comment: This is caused by  `stroke-linecap: round`  increasing the actual dash length by a rounded line cap. So you need to change this property to `stroke-linecap:butt` (no line cap) once the dasharray length is `stroke-dasharray="0px 1px"`. You could do this in css. `[stroke-dasharray="0px 1px"]{stroke-linecap:butt}`

Comment: Thanks this explains it. For my use case, I can have `stroke-linecap: butt`. I would still love to know if there is a way to achieve this with `stroke-linecap: round`.

Comment: line-cap "round" will show a circle if stroke-dash length is 0. So you need some step to hide your stroke. You could also try `[stroke-dasharray="0px 1px"]{stroke-opacity:0}`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is likely due to the way SVG paths are being animated. When you animate the `pathLength` property to make the path disappear, the path's visibility is reduced to zero, but it can leave a tiny dot at the end because the animation engine may not be able to remove the path entirely.

To ensure that the path completely disappears without leaving a dot behind, you can use a different approach. Instead of animating the `pathLength`, you can animate the `stroke` and `opacity` properties of the path.

An updated version of your code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function App() {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => setShowPassword((prev) => !prev)}>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        stroke="#000"
        strokeWidth="1.5"
      >
        <path
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          d="M2.036 12.322a1.012 1.012 0 010-.639C3.423 7.51 7.36 4.5 12 4.5c4.638 0 8.573 3.007 9.963 7.178.07.207.07.431 0 .639C20.577 16.49 16.64 19.5 12 19.5c-4.638 0-8.573-3.007-9.963-7.178z"
        />
        <path
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z"
        />
        <motion.path
          initial={{ stroke: "#000", opacity: 1 }}
          animate={{ stroke: showPassword ? "none" : "#000", opacity: showPassword ? 0 : 1 }}
          exit={{ stroke: "#000", opacity: 1 }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.2, ease: "easeInOut" }}
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          d="M3 3L21 21"
        />
      </svg>
    </button>
  );
}
```

In this code I use the stroke property to control the color of the path, setting it to "none" when you want to hide the path, and setting it back to "#000" when you want to show it.

Comment: This just disappears the path in and out, which is not what I want it to do.